# error while making build with cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Im using cx_freeze to make exe. Python version 3.5.1. The following error im facing. Any help would be really helpful.

```
copying c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\DLLs\_ssl.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\lib\_ssl.pyd
copying c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\lib\pyexpat.pyd
copying c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\DLLs\select.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\lib\select.pyd
copying c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\lib\unicodedata.pyd
copying C:\Users\test\virtuals\uat\lib\site-packages\win32\win32pdh.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\lib\win32pdh.pyd
copying C:\Users\test\virtuals\uat\Scripts\python35.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\lib\python35.dll
copying C:\Users\test\virtuals\uat\lib\site-packages\pypiwin32_system32\pywintypes35.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\lib\pywintypes35.dll
copying C:\Users\test\virtuals\uat\lib\site-packages\win32\win32wnet.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\lib\win32wnet.pyd
copying C:\Users\test\virtuals\uat\DLLs\sqlite3.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\sqlite3.dll
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\test\\virtuals\\uat\\DLLs\\sqlite3.dll'
```

Comment: What version of cx_Freeze are you using?

Comment: Please include your setup script and minimal code so we can try reproducing the problem ourselves.